# File integrity monitoring: How to initialise the database of files on an upgrade?

Tags: monitoring

let's go for what I'm **not** asking first:

- Product recommendations
- End-to-end solutions (which will inevitably end up in an argument)

What I need is a deployment architecture that solves the problem of how to get the new hashes into whatever FIM solution I use on the target deployment environment (node, cloud infrastructure, on-prem server etc).

Currently I am proposing using the following, however it seems a little clunky:

So it would involve:

1. Generating the File list and corresponding hashes during a lab (controlled environment build)
2. Packaging that up with the production build to be sent out to the target environment
3. Loading the database of File/Hash into the FIM solution on the target.

It seems it's possible to do better. I just can't see it at the moment.
[image]